# node server is not serving static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a nodejs application using the express framework. I have used `express.static` to serve my static files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));
```

There is a route that server the **login.html**.

```
// serve login page
app.get('/auth/login', loginPage);
```

and `loginPage` function

```
loginPage(req: any, res: any) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'login.html'));
}
```

Now if I directly hit **http://localhost:8080/login.html** login page gets served with all its css and js files, so static files are getting served.

but when I hit **http://localhost:8080/auth/login** only **login.html** is served and the other css/js files showing **404** status.

If I check the request on browser network window request is for **http://localhost:8080/auth/css/bootstrap.min.css**, this is appending **auth** prefix.

but when I change URL mapping to `/auth` from `/auth/login` then it works fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The problem is most likely not in the Express backend, but in the way you reference the CSS file from the HTML code in login.html. Please include the code where you link to the stylesheet.

Comment: i have used relative urls. `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Well, there you go, if you use a relative URL, it will always be relative to the path of the current page. Try `href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"` (a slash at the beginning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was linking other js and CSS files without using `/` in `href` attribute. Like this

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So I changed all the `href` by appending the `/`

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and now this is working. Thanks to @Patric